# PGrouting number of results in pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix() not right

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, distance-matrix

When running the pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix() on a PostGIS database with 41000 id's  I get only 144000 rows in the matrix. I would have expected much more. 
What am I missing?

I parsed the OSM data with Osm2po, getting these fields:

[image: fields]

The name of my db: ma_2po_4pgr

The SQL I used:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix(
    'SELECT id,  source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM ma_2po_4pgr',
    (SELECT array_agg(id) FROM  ma_2po_4pgr )
);
```

The data looks like this;

[image: The data]

I am on a win7 machine, using PostGIS 2.5.2 on PostgreSQL 11, pgRouting 2.6.2  .

Comment: is your db named ma_2po_4pgr or your edges table? additionally, do you have a table with your nodes?

Comment: The ma_2po_4pgr is my edges table. I didn't have the nodes/vertices. But Osm2PO can create that, as I now have learned. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

If i'm correct you are trying to get the distance from each node in the network to each other node, correct?

[image]

([Image source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphEdge.html))

Your subquery `(SELECT array_agg(id) FROM  ma_2po_4pgr )` returns each unique edge in the network, while'you want this query to return each unique node. To get all the unique nodes you have to select them form the `source` and `target` columns. You can do this via `SELECT DISTINCT((SELECT DISTINCT source FROM ma_2po_4pgr) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT target FROM ma_2po_4pgr))`

You have 41000 ID's, but this does not mean that you expect 41000**2 results, as this table is an edge table, not a node table. One node might be connected to multiple edges. You would expect the amount equal to `COUNT('subquery with the union from previous paragraph')` squared. In other words, from each node to each other node.

So your total query will be like this (not tested):

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix(
    'SELECT id,  source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM ma_2po_4pgr',
    (SELECT array_agg(distinct nodes.id) from 
       (
         (SELECT DISTINCT source as id FROM ma_2po_4pgr)
         UNION
         (SELECT DISTINCT target as id FROM ma_2po_4pgr)
       ) as nodes
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks! In de mean while, I discovered that OSM2PO also is able to supply the vertices table. In config I can add that table.